# MacOS Catalina "Developer Tools" tab is hidden

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-catalina

How do I make the "Developer Tools" section in the System Preferences -> Security & Privacy tab visible?

I had previously had the "System Preferences" -> "Security & Privacy" -> "Privacy" -> "Developer Tools" section visible, but then I made the unwise decision of doing some housecleaning, and removed all items that were in it (Terminal, iTerm, and IntelliJ). Now the "Developer Tools" section is no longer visible, and I can't seem to find a way to reveal it again.

I seem to remember that Xcode originally had something to do with adding the "Developer Tools" section in the first place. I tried `xcode-select --install`, but  already have up-to-date Xcode command line tools, so it does nothing. I'm hoping that I don't have to fully uninstall and re-install Xcode. Surely there must be some terminal command that will re-add "Developer Tools"?

Comment: Have you tried invoking a developer tool (e.g. `lldb -n MyApp`) from a terminal window? If so, what happens?

Comment: Attempting to run a non-notarized tool from the Terminal causes the standard Catalina warning dialog to pop up: "<tool-name> cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified. macOS cannot verify that this app is free from malware." But the "Developer Tools" section is still hidden. I restarted my MacBook but it didn't help.

Comment: Can anyone please change don;t to don't? I don't have the privilege to do that.

Comment: Done. Sorry, that's my "typo of choice".

Answer (score 13):

Oddly, I was using the spctl tool, and discovered that you need to add at least one tool to the list in order to have the 'developer tools' visible in the system preferences -> security & privacy -> Privacy list.

By running the command:

```
spctl developer-mode enable-terminal
```

it will add terminal in a unchecked mode, and then you can add apps as needed, such as iTerm.

Comment: And that's the answer! Doing the above brings back my "Developer Tools" section. Thanks very much!

Comment: Oddly, the only documentation I can find for this is two lines when running `spctl` without arguments.

Comment: I use `tmux`, and this only started working for me after I added `tmux` to the list of Developer Tools as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try downloading and installing the latest `xcode-tools` manually and not from the terminal:

1. Go to https://developer.apple.com/
2. Click on `Account` and sign in (you should already have an account, otherwise sign up)
3. Go to https://developer.apple.com/download/more/
4. Search for `command line tools`
5. Sort by `Release date` and download the latest version
6. Install it and restart your device

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I followed the above process but unfortunately the Developer Tools section is still not visible. I suspect the above would work if I was installing the command line tools for the first time (I think this is how the Developer Tools section appeared the first time on my Mac). But I already have Xcode and the command line tools installed, so I think in that case re-installing them doesn't make the Developer tools section reappear.

Comment: I then tried uninstalling Xcode, rebooting, and then re-installing Xcode. That didn't work either.

Comment: Then I think it's some config file that persisted. Try uninstalling the tools as mentioned here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44597/how-do-i-manually-uninstall-the-developer-tools and I would suggest using a tool like AppCleaner to completely uninstall Xcode from your system https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/

Comment: Did any one got solution for getting Developer Tools to reappear?

Comment: @DouglasPatriarche This link might help you https://docwhat.org/upgrading-to-catalina

Comment: I tried again: completely uninstalled Xcode (using AppZapper) and `sudo rm -r /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`. Rebooted my MBP, then re-installed Xcode from the App Store. Still no "Developer Tools" in the Preferences.